Map Not loading right
Hi I am a student learning Java and I am trying to make my first ever java game but the problem is that my maps are not loading right I made a map loading system that reads the map which is a txt file in 0 (grass), 1(asphalt), 2(sand) these get rode and putted into the tiles array which tile[1] will spawn asphalt and I have 16 maps but my code does not read it so the map does not open and I want to switch maps when player location is either at the right bottom or the right side of the screen. Please Help!
I tried to change map file positions, called it differently and tried debugging it but none worked
package main;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import entity.Player;
import tile.Tile;
public class MapLoader {    
    GamePanel gp;
    Tile[] tile;
    int mapTileNum[][] = new int[18][18];
    //GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
    //MapLoader mapLoader = new MapLoader(gamePanel);   
    private List<String> mapPaths;
    private int currentMapIndex;
    public MapLoader(GamePanel gp) {
        this.gp = gp;
        // Initialize the list and add map file paths in the desired order
        mapPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        mapPaths.add("/maps/map01.txt");
        mapPaths.add("/maps/map02.txt");
        mapPaths.add("/maps/map03.txt");
        mapPaths.add("/maps/map04.txt");
        mapPaths.add("/maps/map05.txt");
        mapPaths.add("/maps/map06.txt");
        mapPaths.add("/maps/map07.txt");
        mapPaths.add("/maps/map08.txt");
        mapPaths.add("/maps/map09.txt");
        mapPaths.add("/maps/map10.txt");
        mapPaths.add("/maps/map11.txt");
        mapPaths.add("/maps/map12.txt");
        mapPaths.add("/maps/map13.txt");
        mapPaths.add("/maps/map14.txt");
        mapPaths.add("/maps/map15.txt");
        mapPaths.add("/maps/map16.txt");      
        setCurrentMapIndex(0);
    }

    public void switchToNextMap() {
        if (currentMapIndex < mapPaths.size() - 1) {
            currentMapIndex++;
            System.out.println("Not Working no new map");
            loadMap(mapPaths.get(currentMapIndex));
        }
    }
    public void switchToPreviousMap() {
        if (currentMapIndex > 0) {
            currentMapIndex--;
            System.out.println("Not Working no old map");
            loadMap(mapPaths.get(currentMapIndex));
        }
    }
    public void loadMaps() {
        // Iterate through the list of map file paths and load each map
        for (String mapPath : mapPaths) {
            loadMap(mapPath);
        }
        
    }
    public void loadMap(String filePath) {
        try {       
            InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            
            int col = 0;
            int row = 0;
            
            while(col < gp.maxScreenCol && row < gp.maxScreenRow) {
                
                String line = br.readLine();
                
                while(col < gp.maxScreenCol) {
                    
                    String numbers[] = line.split(" ");
                    
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(numbers[col]);
                    
                    mapTileNum[col][row] = num;
                    col++;
                }
                if(col == gp.maxScreenCol) {
                    col = 0;
                    row++;
                }
            }
            br.close();
            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Loading map from file: " + filePath);
    }   
    public void switchMap(GamePanel gp, Player player2, String filePathc) {
        loadMap(filePathc); // Load the new map
    }
    public void checkMap(GamePanel gamePanel, Player player, String previousMapFilePath, String nextMapFilePath, String upperMapFilePath) {
        int playerX = player.getX();
        int playerY = player.getY();
        int tileSize = gamePanel.tileSize; // Accessing tileSize from GamePanel instance
 
        if (playerX <= 0) {
            // Player reached left edge of map, switch to the previous map
            switchToPreviousMap();
            // Adjust player position if needed
            player.setX(gamePanel.screenWidth - tileSize);
        } else if (playerX >= gamePanel.screenWidth - tileSize) {
            // Player reached right edge of map, switch to the next map
            switchToNextMap();
            // Adjust player position if needed
            player.setX(0);
        } else if (playerY <= 0) {
            // Player reached top edge of map, switch to the upper map
            switchMap(gamePanel, player, upperMapFilePath);         //maploader
            // Adjust player position if needed
            player.setY(gamePanel.screenHeight - tileSize);
        }    
    }
    public int getCurrentMapIndex() {
        return currentMapIndex;
    }

    public void setCurrentMapIndex(int currentMapIndex) {
        this.currentMapIndex = currentMapIndex;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        MapLoader mapLoader = new MapLoader(gamePanel);
        mapLoader.loadMaps();
    }
    
}

package main;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import entity.Player;
import tile.TileManager;
import main.MapLoader;
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    // Screen Settings
    final int originalTileSize = 16; // 16x16 cars
    final int scale = 3; // Size Scale 32*3
    public final int tileSize = originalTileSize * scale; // 48x48 cars
    public final int maxScreenCol = 18;
    public final int maxScreenRow = 18;
    public final int screenWidth = tileSize * maxScreenCol; // 20 height 960 pixels
    public final int screenHeight = tileSize * maxScreenRow; // 16 width 768 pixels
    Font fpsFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12);   
    //FPS
    int FPS = 70;   
    TileManager tileM = new TileManager(this);
    KeyHandler keyH = new KeyHandler();
    Thread gameThread; // Start and Stop Repeating
    Player player = new Player(this,keyH);
    MapLoader mapLoader = new MapLoader(this); 
    GamePanel gp;
    public GamePanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));
        this.setBackground(Color.gray);     //Color.Black put it gray for testing 
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.addKeyListener(keyH);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        mapLoader.loadMap("/maps/map01.txt");
        //dashboard = new Dashboard(this, keyH);
    }
    public void startGameThread() {
        gameThread = new Thread(this); // this GamePanel
        gameThread.start();
    }

    @Override 
    public void run() {
        mapLoader.loadMaps();
        double drawInterval = 1000000000/FPS;
        double delta = 0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long currentTime;
        long timer = 0;
        int drawCount = 0;  
    while(gameThread != null) {
            
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            
            delta += (currentTime - lastTime) / drawInterval;
            
            timer += (currentTime - lastTime);
            
            lastTime = currentTime;
            
            if(delta >=1) {
                update();
                repaint();
                delta--;
                drawCount++;
            }
            
            if(timer >= 1000000000) {
                System.out.println("FPS: " + drawCount);
                drawCount = 0;
                timer = 0;
            }
        }
        
    }

    public void update() {
        
        player.update();
        
        int playerX = player.getX();
        int playerY = player.getY();
        int tileSize = this.tileSize;

        // Check if the player is at the right edge of the screen
        if (playerX >= screenWidth - tileSize) {
            mapLoader.switchToNextMap();
            // Adjust player position if needed
            player.setX(0);
        } 
        // Check if the player is at the bottom edge of the screen
        else if (playerY >= screenHeight - tileSize) {
            mapLoader.switchToNextMap();
            // Adjust player position if needed
            player.setY(0);
        }
                
    }
    

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        tileM.draw(g2);
        
        player.draw(g2);
        
        player.draw(g2);
        
        g2.dispose(); // to save ram
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("F1 Monaco");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(gamePanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame on the screen
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        MapLoader mapLoader = new MapLoader(gamePanel);
        mapLoader.loadMaps();
    }

}


Have you actually run your code step-by-step in the debugger?

No I do not know if eclipse has step by step debugger

Yes, it certainly does.  See https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/june/article1.php  (or similar).

Hey I fixed the issue it was that I had no image icons setted up for the map in maploader so I added them and now all the maps load good
